# Link from Classic asp app to an AngularJS app with URL parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a angularJS application and a old classic asp application that will have a link to the new app.  The classic asp app will pass a changing URL parameter to the angular app. like this.
http://testURL.com/Notes/PresentationHtml/index.html#/Main/11111111

No matter what I do the URL always gets truncated down to
http://testURL.com/Notes/PresentationHtml/index.html#/Main/

I am using ui-router not the built in $routeProvider routing.
Below is my routing configuration and it works fine if I type the url in the browser window.

```
var myApplication = angular.module('myApplication', ['ui.router', 'ajoslin.promise-tracker', 'ngGrid']);

var root = '/';
var home = root + 'Notes';
var apiUrl = home + '/notesapi/Notes';
var htmlHome = home + '/PresentationHtml/';

myApplication.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    var index = {
        name: 'index',
        url: '/Main/:accountId',
        templateUrl: htmlHome + 'Main.html'
    };

    var errorstate = {
        name: 'errorstate',
        url: '/ApiUnhandledError/:appCode',
        templateUrl: htmlHome + 'ApiUnhandledError.html'
    };



    $stateProvider.state(index);

}]);


myApplication.run(function ($state) {

    $state.go('index');
});
```

Comment: What exactly does the html source output by asp have for the href?

Comment: This is the contents of the Href-

http://testURL.com/Notes/PresentationHtml/index.html#/Main/11111111

Comment: The 11111111 is what it loses.

Comment: This was resolved.  I'm not sure what solved it I think it just had to get warmed up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the passed in variable in the controller solved the issue.  I'm not sure why it was not working initially could have had something to do with UI-Router. This is my code after the account id parameter is passed in.

```
if ($stateParams.accountId != null && $stateParams.accountId.trim() != '') {
    $scope.qsAccountArg = $stateParams.accountId
    messageFactory.setAccountId($scope.qsAccountArg);
} else {
    $scope.qsAccountArg = '';
    $scope.ShowAccountFilter = true;
}
```